# Approval Workflow and add workflow to a Task

Tags: workflow, tasks

If I create a Approval Workflow I can't add a workflow to a Task Created by the workflow. How could I add a wokflow to a Tasc created by approval workflow.

Please help:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you creating Workflow with an Approval you must select which list will be used for Workflow Tasks ( *url: /site/WorkflowTasks/AllItems.aspx* ).
If you want to add another workflow to task, you must create new workflow in **Workflow Tasks library** for tasks. Make sure you set this workflow **Run when Created**

Comment: Yes but I wan't add task to task which was created by approval workflow. To this task I tried to add.

Comment: I am sorry maybe i am dumb but i dont know how you though that...

Comment: If I creating a approval workflow it is creating a Task list. And on this Task List I want to create a workflow wchich is fire if someone has got a overdue tasks.

Comment: I found out which sort of problem it is. It is why because the workflow havent been  maide before element is created. After the workflow is created it connect with element's, but only new.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update item on which workflow started i.e., 
On item added one task created so that time updates your new column in an item with task created column and check on it for overdue tasks.

You can use pause event in workflow for waiting for an overdue date for the task.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/remainder-workflow-pause-for-specific-duration-in-sharepoint/